# PHP mail() is not functioning

Tags: javascript, php, email, smtp

I'm trying to communicate between JavaScript and PHP since last two days. After reading numerous tutorials, suggestions and solutions of the similar encountered issues of other people I am unable to succeed as intended yet. So to speak, I'm programming over a domain of mine, not locally.

### **The goal is to:**

Send to my e-mail address a very well formatted string from a well-formed object in my JavaScript. In order to do that I do understand that a PHP script is needed to be executed with it's famous email() function.

### **Steps taken for the goal:**

1. Have a functioning JavaScript (with no errors) that creates and fills data to the above-mentioned JS object (name it: '*person*');
2. Format it into a good string (because I want it to send as a plain text format not an HTML yet);
3. Have jQuery's **$.ajax()** call to do a **[CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing)** interaction with the server-side, which is a PHP containing the necessary Headers and the code to send a simple mail to the designated destination (e.g. my e-mail address).
4. (Optional) Have undergone GZIP compression, minifying HTML/CSS/JS to produce a faster loading content to the client.

### **What's the ISSUE?**

My AJAX code runs smooth with no errors but not as expected and intended. Instead of jumping/entering into SUCCESS, it goes right away on ERROR custom-made functions and I don't seem to be able to decipher what could possibly be going wrong.

I'm going to post below both JS (AJAX call) and the PHP script that I'm using to accomplish the goal mentioned above.

JavaScript (***updated***) :

```
function submitOnClick() {
    var full_name = "John Doe";
    var profile_person = "--[Name: John, Surname: Doe, Birthday: 25/02/1950]--";    
    var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    hr.open("POST", "submit_to_email.php", true);
    hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    hr.send("full_name=" + full_name + "&" + "person=" + profile_person);
    hr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
            var data = hr.responseText;
            console.log("PHP responded with: " + data);
        }
    }
}
```

PHP script (***updated***):

```
<?php
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); 
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Content-Range, Content-Disposition, Content-Description');
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    $postvars = $_POST['person'];
//var_dump($postvars);

if (isset($postvars)) { 
  $to = 'to@gmail.com';
  $subject = 'Subject Title';
  $email_message = $postvars;
  $headers = 'From: noreply@mydomain.com'."\r\n".
  'Reply-To: noreply@mydomain.com'."\r\n" .
  'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
  $checker = @mail($to, $subject, $email_message, $headers);

  if ($checker == true) {
      echo 'Mail was sent to'.$to;
  }
  else {
      echo 'Mail was NOT sent to'.$to;
  }
}
?>

<?php
  die();
?>
```

### **UPDATE**

$.ajax() wasn't necessary at all instead started to use plain vanilla JS with XMLHttpRequest() method. Content is sent successfully to my PHP file BUT by checking mail() if it's true/false (sent/not) results in ***FALSE***. A configuration file is needed to provide PHP the information of my SMTP setup. I'm using Arvixe hosting and it has an IIS server installed in it. I'm kinda new to web hosting and maintaining a domain thus I don't know whether I should configure the web.config file in my project folder or add extensional PHP config files.

Comment: I can't see where you're getting the $_POST['some'] data

Comment: $postvars = file_get_contents('php://input'); is similar to using $_POST['some]. If I'm obliged to use the latter than I have to use an object into 'data' property of ajax, not the array.

Comment: Try doing that and printing out for debugging. If you can get the appropriate data then something's wrong with the way you're parsing.

Use this for your JSON http://jsonlint.com/

Plus aren't you missing a semicolon at     error: onFailure
}) ?

Comment: Semicolon missing: true. Updated now. How do I achieve printing the parsed value in php to the console or anywhere in my DOM elements?

Comment: Debug your php code using something like Google Chrome's debugger and check if PHP is returning an error, which most likely it is.

Comment: I tried your exact code. I had to comment out the `mail()` function, as it is not well configured on my PC so it gave me an error, but after doing this, I got nothing wrong. Your problem surely is on the `mail()` throwing an error, thus sending a 500 error code or making the output not valid JSON, so jQuery considers it an error.

Comment: Trying to debug with the Chrome's extension: XDebug Helper...will provide new information when I succeed with this new tool.

Comment: @BenjaminC. Indeed. Although when I put static values into the mail() php function, everything as a string than I received a Success on ajax() in javascript but again the mail was not send to my email address. Going nuts soon...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After days of research I've finally found one possible and very efficient solution. The problem was relying onto that my domain is set to run on a Windows Server 2008+ with IIS hosting hence PHP's mail() function was incomplete to execute a mail.

Solution was and is : **PHPMailer** a very common and notably top used php library especially designed to deliver confident and simple code to developers. I've downloaded it from **[GitHub](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)** source as a zip and then extract it. After that created a blank new php file and copy/paste the demo script on how-to send a mail and altered it to my needs. Finally uploaded both PHPMailer folder and the newly created script to my domain. After executing the script manually I've received mail(s) in my inbox and not as a spam. This **[tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CizDkNNcLRg)**
saved me a life too.
The script is as it follows:

```
<? php
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Content-Range, Content-Disposition, Content-Description');
    header('Content-Type: application/json');

    $postvars = $_POST['person'];
    if (isset($postvars)) {
        $to = 'recipient@gmail.com';
        $subject = 'Some Title';
        $email_message = $postvars;

        require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php'; // The script needed to be called in order to executed
        // further commands below

        $mail = new PHPMailer;

        $mail - > isSMTP(); // Set mailer to use SMTP
        $mail - > Host = 'smtp.mydomain.com'; // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
        $mail - > SMTPAuth = true; // Enable SMTP authentication
        $mail - > Username = 'mymail@mydomain.com'; // SMTP username
        $mail - > Password = 'password_here'; // SMTP password
        $mail - > SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
        $mail - > Port = 465; // TCP port to connect to

        $mail - > CharSet = 'UTF-8'; // Character set specified because I use "ë" and other ones
        $mail - > From = 'mymail@mydomain.com'; // The same email address as specified above for authentication
        $mail - > FromName = 'Myself'; // The name of the sender (optional)
        $mail - > addAddress($to, 'recipients_name'); // Add a recipient & name (optional)
        $mail - > addReplyTo('mymail@mydomain.com', 'Some text'); // To who to reply
        $mail - > WordWrap = 70; // Wrapping words
        $mail - > isHTML(true); // if TRUE , format is HTML or FALSE, format is Plain Text

        $mail - > Subject = $subject;
        $mail - > Body = $email_message; //Plain or HTML formatted string
        $mail - > AltBody = $email_message; //The same as Body BUT it has to be Plain text always

        if (!$mail - > send()) {
            echo 'Message could not be sent.';
            echo 'Mailer Error: '.$mail - > ErrorInfo;
        } else {
            echo 'Message has been sent';
        }
    } 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the only thing that you need to put the header of success with relevant code 200 to your answer.

if you answer is in json format jquery read that code to redirect to a success or error handler.

check header php function:

[Header Function PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/function.header.php)

tell me if works.

Comment: I've looked into that too. But the problem is IF it was going to work w/o the OK response Header it would send an e-mail in the first row. So I guess the problem is not in there. As far as I can tell the problem lies either on contentType/dataType in ajax being inappropriate to the headers mentioned in PHP.

Comment: try to check data variable in failure or success handler and looking for some problem in the json answer; remember check the success or failure of mail function to send the response (http://php.net/manual/es/function.mail.php).